# Cryptography - Secret Key split up in parts

Tags: split, key

I am using triple DES. I have secret key of 24 bytes.
This needs to be loaded into system for which required 3 Components (HEX) and distribute those components to 3 different custodians.

Need help how to generate these 3 components for the secret key. I have searched and not getting clear idea on it.

Some where they told to use xor and not much clear

Comp 1 -random seed xor secret key
Comp 2 -?
Comp 3 -?

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate two 24-byte random values (`r1` and `r2`).
2. Exclusive-OR (XOR) `key` with `r1`:

`key ^ r1 = xor1`

3. XOR `xor1` with `r2`:

`xor1 ^ r2 = xor2`

This is congruent with:

`xor1 = xor2 ^ r2`

5. Now substitute back into the first equation:

`key = r1 ^ xor2 ^ r2`

So your key-split function will simply execute: `xor = key ^ r1 ^ r2`, and you then distribute the non-key primitives: `xor`, `r1`, and `r2`.